# Reorder rows according to the original dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes A and B. B is a copy of A. I did some manipulation on B and now both have the identical structure except that, B has all the rows sorted by the column "title", eg: title0, title1..., whereas A has a column "title" that has no order, eg: title24, title13.... I want B to be rearranged like titles in A. I tried to make a list of title column of A and did a reindex on B, which did the trick but then my title column became the index column of B, which I don't want. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Code:

```
title=['tit12','tit22','tit21','tit42','tit41','tit45','tit33','tit36','tit32']
col2=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
d={
    "title":title,
    "col2":col2,
}
A= pd.DataFrame(d)
title2=['tit12','tit21','tit22','tit32','tit33','tit36','tit41','tit42','tit45']
col22=['i','h','g','f','e','d','c','b','a']
d2={
    "title":title2,
    "col2":col22,
}
B= pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

[image]

As you can see from the picture, I want B to be rearranged like A.

Comment: As you know, to effectively answer questions we need to see some sample data and expected output. Can you provide the missing detail please.

Comment: Did you try `A.sort_values('title')`?

Comment: Hi I have updated the question, I cant use sort as it will either do ascending or descending, I want rows in the order A has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
B = B.iloc[B.title.map(dict(zip(A.title,range(len(A)))))]

B
   title col2
0  tit12    i
2  tit22    g
1  tit21    h
8  tit45    a
6  tit41    c
7  tit42    b
4  tit33    e
3  tit32    f
5  tit36    d
```

Or we try `pd.Categorical`

```
B = B.iloc[pd.Categorical(B.title,A.title.unique()).argsort()]
   title col2
0  tit12    i
2  tit22    g
1  tit21    h
7  tit42    b
6  tit41    c
8  tit45    a
4  tit33    e
5  tit36    d
3  tit32    f
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the index for both dataframes to 'title', reindex `B` with `A`, using [reindex-like](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html) - you could just use plain [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) as well - and then reset the index :

```
B.set_index("title").reindex_like(A.set_index("title")).reset_index()


   title    col2
0   tit12   i
1   tit22   g
2   tit21   h
3   tit42   b
4   tit41   c
5   tit45   a
6   tit33   e
7   tit36   d
8   tit32   f
```

You could also use `merge` :

```
pd.merge(B, A["title"], how="right")

   title    col2
0   tit12   i
1   tit22   g
2   tit21   h
3   tit42   b
4   tit41   c
5   tit45   a
6   tit33   e
7   tit36   d
8   tit32   f
```

If you want the indices, similar to the accepted answer by @BENY, you could combine [take](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.take.html) and [get_indexer_for](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer_for.html) - if your indices are unique, you can just use [get_indexer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html):

```
B.take(pd.Index(A.title).get_indexer_for(B.title))

    title   col2
0   tit12   i
2   tit22   g
1   tit21   h
8   tit45   a
6   tit41   c
7   tit42   b
4   tit33   e
3   tit32   f
5   tit36   d
```